# Is interruption between task is possible in Non RTOS system

Tags: interrupt, rtos

If I have a non-RTOS single core system, can one task, say taskA interrupt another task, say taskB, where neither taskA or taskB are interrupt routines?  Or is interruption of one task by another only possible through ISR(interrupt service routines) on non-RTOS systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your system to have more than one non-ISR thread implies that there is some sort of multi-tasking - and multi-tasking is not exclusive to an RTOS.  One task "interrupting" another is known as *preemption*.  Preemption requires a *preemptive scheduler*, while an RTOS is necessarily a pre-emptive scheduler, so also are Windows and Linux for example - but these are not *real-time* since scheduling and preemption is not deterministic.

Preemptive multi-tasking is necessary to support preemption, but real-time deterministic scheduling is not required.  Preemption however is not necessary to multi-tasking; some systems (Notably 16 bit versions of Windows prior to Win95, and MacOS prior to OSX) are cooperative multitasking systems where a running task must yield the CPU to allow other tasks to run.

In a preemptive multitasking system, the scheduler executes on exit from the interrupt context and whenever a task invokes a schedulable event (such as giving a semaphore, queuing a message or releasing a mutex.  If when the scheduler runs a task becomes ready to run and the scheduling policy requires or allows it to preempt the current task, a context switch will occur.

So in short one non-ISR thread or process "interrupting" another requires an OS that supports preemption, which need not be an RTOS.

Comment: Indeed, in the embedded world, "RTOS" is (wrongly) used as a synonym for "preemptive scheduler"; even worse, "RTOS" is used *instead* of the correct term all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Control must be given to the task scheduler in order for a context switch to occur.  That can happen as a result of an interrupt if the interrupt handler is designed to call the scheduler.  Or it can happen as a result of some function call (such as yield, post, or pend) if that function calls the scheduler.

This task scheduler could be part of an RTOS.  Or maybe it's some minimal task switching kernel that you don't consider to be an RTOS .  Regardless, some sort of scheduler must get control in order to perform a task context switch.

Comment: Good succinct answer, but it need not be only an RTOS or a "minimal task scheduler" - all modern GPOS such as WIndows, Linux and OSX for example have preemptive schedulers.